# NHibernate not mapping inherited properties with ComposedId

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

It seems to me this is a bug, but want to confirm my understanding of how this should work before I submit this to NHibernate bugtracker.

My project is configured to use explicit model mapping and restore the database every thime it is run. I have a simple base class that defines a property. A subclass wants to combine that property with its own to make a composite Primary Key as follows:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int InheritedId { get; set; }
}

public class Subclass : BaseClass
{
    public int OwnId { get; set; }
}

public class SubclassMap : ClassMapping<Subclass>
{
    public SubclassMap()
    {
        Table("Subclass");
        ComposedId(x => {
            x.Property(p => p.InheritedId);
            x.Property(p => p.OwnId);
        });
    }
}
```

#### Expected result

A table in my database named *Subclass* with two columns in it: *InheritedId* and *OwnId*, and a primary key composed of these two columns.

#### Actual result

A table in the database named *Subclass* with two columns in it: *InheritedId* and *OwnId*, and a primary key **composed of just *OwnId***.

#### Workarounds

If I copy the property to *Subclass* (marking it as `new`), the above works just fine.

#### Hypothesis

From looking at NHibernate source it seems that the `TypeExtensions.DecodeMemberAccessExpression()` method returns *MemberInfo* for *InheritedId* that specifies *BaseClass* as its *ReflectedType*, while a little later when the declared model is finally parsed, `typeof(Subclass).GetProperties()` returns *MemberInfo* that specifies *Subclass* as the reflected type. The two are different, and therefore `ModelMapper.MapRootClass()` is unable to find it among the *ComposedIds* to be mapped it earlier compiled.

#### Help!

Have you come across this problem? Am I doing something weird or should be above be submitted to NHibernate bugtracker as incorrect behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have found a legitimate bug.

The generated mapping should be:

```
<class name="Subclass" table="Subclass">
  <composite-id>
    <key-property name="OwnId" />
    <key-property name="InheritedId" />
  </composite-id>
</class>
```

But instead it is:

```
<class name="Subclass" table="Subclass">
  <composite-id>
    <key-property name="OwnId" />
  </composite-id>
  <property name="InheritedId" />
</class>
```

You can open the issue in Jira.

Also, if you have the time, you can fork it in Github, fix it (without breaking any tests) and submit a pull request.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. I'll have a look around to see if I can find out why this is the case and whether it's a simple fix or too complex for me to handle with my limited knowledge of NHibernate architecture.

Comment: After some further digging it seems that it may not necessarily be a bug. NHibernate would prefer to map properties from the superclass in a separate mapping and to a separate table. Now I'm trying to see if I can somehow force table-per-concrete-class in Loquacious, and whether it will have the desired consequences of allowing me to map `InheritedId` in subclasses.